# Distribution of A=1/B, where B is normally distributed.

Tags: probability-distributions

Take a variable, B, which has standard normal distribution.

Let A = 1/B. What is the distribution of A?

One way to go about this problem would be to take the CDF of the standard normal curve, and to use this to compute points on the new distribution. For instance, the probability that B>1 is approximately 0.16. Therefore, the probability that 01) = 0.34. In the same way, P(A>0.5) = 0.48. This method can yield the CDF of A to an arbitrary degree of precision. However, I would like to know the exact function of A's distribution.

Comment: According to wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Reciprocal_normal_distribution there does not seem to exist a closed form.

Comment: No closed form? What the... The most usual change of variable theorem yields readily $$f_{1/X}(y)=\frac1{y^2}f_X\left(\frac1y\right)$$

Comment: Today $3$ goals by Thomas Delaney!!